# Regex to match particular HTTP header value in Java

Tags: java, android, regex

Context: I'm working on an automation flow in Automate (Android app). I have the output of a `curl` in a String, listing headers with values. I'd like to parse the `Location` header value out of it with a regex.

```
Foo: bar
Location: http://localhost
Abc: xyz
```

How can I get my `http://localhost` value with a single regex? The context of the Android app aside, I'm trying this in Intellij against jdk8: if the regex works there, it should work in the app too. I've gone over some parts of the manual (learning about reluctant quantifiers in the process), but nothing works. My final attempt was `(?iums).*?^Location:\s*(https://\S+)$.*`, but alas, still no match for some reason I just can't figure out.

Much appreciated

Edit: for convenience:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String match = Pattern.compile("(?iums).*?^Location:\\s*(https://\\S+)$.*")
        .matcher("Foo: bar\nLocation: https://foo.bar\nabc: xyz")
        .group(1);
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Strangely, Intellij claims it *does* match:

[image: intellij match]

Comment: You forgot to run the matcher with `.find()` or `matches()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's it indeed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something else, you could use an HTTP client submit a request, and parse the response programmatically.

A number of candidates exist out there, you can use Apache Http Client https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

I hope that helps.

Comment: No, I'm restricted to Android/busybox shell commands and Automate's API